# Getting the unicode characters of a string

Tags: python, unicode, pyside

I'm getting a string from a qt widget, and I'm trying to convert the non ascii characters (eg. €) into hex unicode characters (eg. x20ac)

Currently I'm doing to see the unicode character is this:

```
currentText = self.rich_text_edit.toPlainText() # this string is the € symbol
print("unicode char is: {0}".format(unicode_text))
```

This provides me with the error:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

That's actually what I want, right there, the 20ac.

How do I get at that?

If I do this:

```
unicode_text = str(unicode_text).encode('string_escape')
print unicode_text #returns \xe2\x82\xac
```

It returns 3 characters, all of them wrong, I'm going round in circles :)

I know it's a fairly basic question, but I've never had to worry about unicode before.

Many thanks in advance,
Ian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\xe2\x82\xac` is the UTF-8 encoding of Unicode `\x20ac`.

Think of it as follows, Unicode is a 1 to 1 mapping between an integer number and a character similar to ASCII, except Unicode goes much much higher in its number of integer to character mappings.

Your `€` symbol has a integer value of `8364` (or `\x20ac` in hex), which is far too big to fit into an 8-bit value of 256 - and so `\x20ac` is broken down into 3 individual bytes of `\xe2\x82\xac`. This is a very high level overview, but I'd really recommend you take a look at this excellent explanation from Scott Hanselman:

[Why the #AskObama Tweet was Garbled on Screen.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhyTheAskObamaTweetWasGarbledOnScreenKnowYourUTF8UnicodeASCIIAndANSIDecodingMrPresident.aspx)

As for your question, you can simply do

```
>>> print "unicode code point is: {0}".format(hex(ord(unicode_text)))
unicode code point is: 0x20ac
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `ord` and `hex`:

```
>>> hex(ord(u"€"))
 '0x20ac'
```